# Different results between Nokogiri and real browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, nokogiri, open-uri

The target url is: *http://courts.delaware.gov/opinions/List.aspx?ag=all+courts*

It seems to only retrieve the first 10 links, while a real browser retrieves 50 links.

Here's some sample code to reproduce the error:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

doc=Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://courts.delaware.gov/opinions/List.aspx?ag=all+courts", 'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0'))
p "there are missing links" if doc.css('strong a').size < 50
```

When opening the file produced by `open("http://courts.delaware.gov/opinions/List.aspx?ag=all+courts", 'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0')`, I see the full and expected HTML.

The resulting `doc` returned from Nokogiri is truncated, with closing HTML tags after the 10th link and no additional content.

This leads me to believe there's something that is misleading the Nokogiri HTML parser to terminate early.

EDIT: It looks like there's something malformed in the HTML. When I remove the last `<tr>...</tr>` element, Nokogiri grabs more links. I'm still not sure what the problem is exactly, and how to configure Nokogiri to grab everything.

EDIT2: The problem is that Nokogiri stops parsing after encountering a special character and invalid UTF-8, `\x002`. There's probably some way to sanitize or force encoding before it is parsed by Nokogiri to fix this bug.

Comment: It's a malformed page. There are closing `</body>` and `</html>` tags at line 96 and 97 in the HTML. Browsers don't really care, (they do care but they don't do anything about it) but parsers aren't so friendly. Nokogiri might be doing fixups, or it might be throwing away the trailing content.

Comment: When you encounter a page that is really messed up, like this looks to be, sometimes you have to write code to massage it into a shape that Nokogiri can swallow without burping. Often that means selectively removing and adding tags prior to handing the content to Nokogiri.